# Restart Wi-Fi Hotspot automatically on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, 17.04, hot-spot

I'm using a hotspot on Ubuntu 17.04 to share my Internet connection with other devices. But when I restart or suspend the computer, I need to activate the hotspot manually each time.

Is there some option, script, or command to launch the hotspot automatically after wakeup?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can do it with Network Manager.
Check the name of the connection which represents the hotspot that you want to start when its active or just guest

```
nmcli con show
```

then to make it start automatically

```
nmcli con mod <connection-name> connection.autoconnect yes
```

test it with reboot

Comment: I would add that `nmcli con show <connection-name>` lists all parameters including autoconnect, so it can be used to check status without rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

You could open a terminal and type

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid YOURSSID
```

If it brings up your Hotspot you could create a file using

```
gnome-session-properties
```

to let your Hotspot start on system startup. But I am not sure if this will also do the trick if your machine comes up from suspend.

Maybe then you would need to create two files with

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/your-script 
sudo touch /lib/systemd/system-sleep/your-script
```

Edit them both with

```
sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/your-script 
sudo -H gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/your-script
```

and paste

```sh
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
  post|thaw)
    echo "waking up..."
    nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid YOURSSID 
 ;;
 esac
```

into them. Then you would need to make them both executable with

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/pm/sleep.d/your-script
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/your-script
```

and try your luck again...

The script works on my machine, but as I am connected only wireless and I am using the same name of the SSID for the test of the Hotspot and after a while, even after sleep, the adapter connects to the standard wifi operations and the Hotspot is getting disabled and wifi is getting enabled.