# Can I create a keyboard shortcut to kicking on my WiFi hotspot?

Tags: shortcut-keys, hot-spot

How might I create a keyboard shortcut for turning on my WiFi hotspot?

I tried using the keyboard shortcut menu in the settings, with `nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid ____ password ____` for turning on the hotspot and `nmcli device disconnect _____` for turning it off.

But that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to create scripts to connect and disconnect WiFi hotspot. See this  Q&A for options: [How to connect to WiFi from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461825/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line)

To see list of available WiFi hotspots ()

```
nmcli d wifi list
```

Sample Script to connect:

```
#!/bin/bash
nmcli d connect <WifiInterface>
```

Sample Script to disconnect:

```
#!/bin/bash
nmcli d disconnect <WifiInterface>
```

Marks the scripts as executable with `chmod`:

```
sudo chmod a+x /path/to/script-name
```

Assign shortcut keys to scripts: [How do I setup keyboard macros?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866619/how-do-i-setup-keyboard-macros/866629#866629)

NOTE: Have your password automatically saved with your WiFi profile so it doesn't have to be reentered every time it is started up.

Comment: Can I just list the commands in custom keyboard shortcuts? That's what I'm currently trying.

Comment: Woohoo! That worked. Thanks for the help : ) I'll post what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up listing these two commands in custom keyboard shortcuts in the settings.

`nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid network-name password network-password`

and

`nmcli device disconnect ______` where ______ is something like wlp123 or something. You can get this value if you use the first command in the terminal.

Then I listed those in the keyboard shortcuts. It wasn't obvious what key combos worked and didn't work. Some combos just didn't work sadly.