# How to revert automatic hot-spot setup?

Tags: wireless, 21.04, hot-spot

Long ago I set my Ubuntu 21.04 to automatically start a WiFi hot-spot at startup or simply why turning on the WiFi (I was keeping my laptop connected to Ethernet all day and I needed WiFi nearby).

I don't remember what procedure did I follow to do that, but now I would like to undo that somehow. How can I do that?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to undo [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928594/restart-wi-fi-hotspot-automatically-on-ubuntu-17-04) with the following command:

```
nmcli con mod <connection-name> connection.autoconnect no
```

In my case the name of the `<connection-name>` was `Hotspot`.